# RPushbullet doesn't work with scheduled tasks

Tags: r, notifications, schedule

I am using the RPushbullet package to notify me when my scripts are finished running. This works really well. Now, I have some scripts that I would like to run periodically, via the windows scheduler. I have found a way to do this via the windows scheduler, as described here:
https://datasciencediving.wordpress.com/2017/10/17/2039/
This also works, when I have no notification. When I include the RPushbullet lines in the code, the script works well in R, but not when scheduled (I am using Windows7).

In order to get some more information about the problem, I ran the script from the command line. I thought the problem could have been with my proxy not beeing passed through properly, or something similar, so I tested this with the simple script below:

```
# file = test.R
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)
library(XML)
library(RPushbullet)
library(curl)
library(httr)

Sys.setenv(http_proxy = "MyProxy:MyPort")
fn <- "MyPath\\TestFile.txt"

#test I can access internet and write to file
MapAd <- "http://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/chembl/SureChEMBL/data/map/"
webpage <- MapAd %>% read_html() %>% htmlParse()
t1Links <- data.frame(xpathSApply(webpage, '//a', xmlGetAttr, 'href'),stringsAsFactors=F)
write(t1Links[1,1], file=fn, append=T) # this gets written into file - to here works

# send pb
pbPost("note", "Testing", "Here a message",apikey ="XXXX") # this line is only successful running the script 'manually' in R, but not when using the scheduler or through the command line
```

Then I run the code in the command line using

```
Rscript -e "source('MyPath/test.R')"
```

The error message I get in the command line is the following:
`Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(pburl, handle = h) :
Timeout was reached: Connection timed out after 10000 milliseconds
Ruft auf: source ... pbPost --> lapply --> FUN .createPush --> <Annonymous>
Ausfuehrung angehalten.`

what can I do to get the Pushbullet notification working for scheduled tasks?

Comment: Does RPushbullet ever worked? Is it blocked by your proxy or something?

Comment: Yep, RPushbullet works really well when the tasks aren't scheduled - for example to let me know that a script has finished running.